# Критические секции в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

нужна помощь в создании аналога критической секции на javascript, то есть вход следующей функции в критическую секцию должен выполняться после выхода предыдущей, вот что есть сейчас:

```js
class CriticalSection {
  constructor() {
    this._flag = false;
  }

  enter() {
    if (!this._flag) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._flag = true;
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 3000);
      });
    } else {
      //здесь нужно какое-то ограничение
    }
  }

  leav() {
    this._flag = false;
  }
}
let cs = new CriticalSection();

cs.enter().then((value) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`1`);
    cs.leav();
  }, 2000)
}, null);


cs.enter().then((value) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`2`);
    cs.leav();
  }, 2000)
}, null);
```

Comment: не понятно какое поведение ты рассчитываешь получить

Comment: Сначала в критическую секцию заходит один процесс, который ее занимает _flag = true, возвращается промис с результатом onFullFilled и в консоли печатается 1, затем секция освобождается _flag = false и туда заходит второй процесс, так же отрабатывает как и первый и печатает в консоль 2 . Второй вызов должен ожидать завершения первого.

Comment: @Grundy, пока ты тут выясняешь, я уже сделал :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проверка на закрытие верной секции не требуется, можно заменить токен на флаг.

```js
class CriticalSection {
  constructor() {
    this.queue = []
    this.token = null
  }

  enter() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.token) {
        this.queue.push(() => resolve(this.token = {}))
      } else {
        resolve(this.token = {})
      }
    })
  }

  leave(token) {
    if (this.token !== token) {
      throw new Error("Leaving the wrong section")
    }
    
    if (this.queue.length) {
      this.queue.shift()()
    } else {
      this.token = null
    }
  }
}

let cs = new CriticalSection();

cs.enter().then(token => {
  console.log("Entered #1")
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Timeout #1");
    cs.leave(token);
    console.log("Left #1");
  }, 2000)
}, null);

cs.enter().then(token => {
  console.log("Entered #2")
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Timeout #2");
    cs.leave(token);
    console.log("Left #2");
  }, 2000)
}, null);
```

Comment: зачем токен наружу тащить? Допиши хоть пояснение как это все работает :)

Comment: @Grundy, в смысле наружу? Зачем он в поле? Ну чтобы методы нормально в прототипе лежали. Я не фанат нижних подчёркиваний для приватных данных. Или зачем он вообще нужен? Тогда для проверки того, что мы выходим именно из той секции, в которую зашли. Вроде даже в ответе написано.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за ответ, помог разобраться что к чему)